# how to stop Xcode iOS unit tests if a fatalerror is hit?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest, xctestcase

How can I stop Xcode iOS unit tests if a fatalerror is hit?

That is in case I have 10 unit tests, but it happens that the code it calls for unit test number 5 has a coding problem (** coding issue in this case is in the test case and setup code **) and is throwing a fatalError.  So in this case the unit testing stops there and does not continue to other test cases in that test class.

(not sure if this is the intended operational / process for good unit testing or not? )

Comment: Will you be able provide a sample code for that? And which version of Xcode are you using? I am able to continue my tests here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy fix for this. In case of an uncaught (objc) exception or a failed `assert` the process that runs the unit tests did receive either a mach exception or a unix signal.

Matt Gallagher has a nice solution for this, which he presents [in this blog post](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/02/02/partial-functions-part-two-catching-precondition-failures.html).

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

    continueAfterFailure = false
}
```

Comment: setting "continueAfterFailure = true" didn't seem to work

Comment: I think continueAfterFailure is just for XCTAssert failures

Answer (score 2):

A related problem I had was stopping the unit test with a breakpoint when it fails, so that I can see the issue, without having to click or scroll through tons of test output.

Making a unit test failure breakpoint is simple, but wasn't easy to find.

Xcode 8+ there is a new breakpoint that you can add called a "Test Failure Breakpoint".

1. Click on Breakpoints (Left Panel ... Command + 7)
2. Click on + (Bottom left corner)
3. Click on "Test Failure Breakpoint"

[image: Xcode Unit Test Failure Breakpoint]

#### References

- [Debugging Tests with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/06-debugging_tests.html)

Answer (score -1):

It is good practice to write safe code everywhere, including your unit tests.

Regarding your problem, as Oleg Danu replied, you should set `continueAfterFailure = false`.

The next step is to add following before your test can crash.

```
var optionalVariable: Int?
XCTAssertNotNil(optionalVariable)
```

I recommend to add it into `setUp()`

In this way your test will stop before crashing Xcode, and you don't need to set any breakpoints.